# Orthogonal Basis for symmetric operators

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, symmetric-matrices

for each $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ let $E_{ij} \in \mathrm{End}\mathbf{V}$
be the linear operator defined by
\begin{equation*}
   E_{ij} \mathbf{e}_k = \langle \mathbf{e}_j,\mathbf{e}_k \rangle \mathbf{e}_i, \quad 1 \leq k \leq n.
  \end{equation*}

prove that
$\mathcal{S} = \{ E_{ij} + E_{ji} \colon 1 \leq i \leq j \leq n\}$ is an orthogonal basis of the subspace
$\mathrm{Sym}\mathbf{V}$ of $\mathrm{End}\mathbf{V}$ consisting of symmetric operators.
What is $\dim \mathrm{Sym}\mathbf{V}$?

I know that for symmetric operators, the operator equals its transpose which I believe is why $\mathcal{S}$ is given by $\{ E_{ij} + E_{ji} \colon 1 \leq i \leq j \leq n\}$ (as these two matrices are transposes). I'm not sure how to give a formal proof however or calculate the dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$dim(Sym(V))=\dfrac12 n(n+1)$$

because $Sym(V)$ has the following basis made of the $\dfrac12 n(n-1)$ matrices:

$$F_{i,j}=E_{i,j}+E_{j,i}$$

to which we must add the $n$ matrices $E_{i,i}$.

Remark: This basis is orthogonal (not orthonormal) for the dot product you have mentionned in your other question :

$$(A,B)=Tr(A^TB)$$

Comment: Why is the dimension of the two matrices 1/2n(n-1)?

Comment: I should have added : the number of matrices $F_{ij}$ **where $i<j$**. Think (once more) to the way we have to fill in the entries of a symmetric matrix : n choices for the first row + (n-1) for the next row + etc... which makes $n+(n-1)+(n-2)+ ... + 1 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

Comment: got it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably $e_1, \dots, e_n$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$? And presumably the inner product on $\text{End}(V)$ is the dot product with respect to the basis $\{E_{ij}\}$. The proof is immediate once you realize that $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with a $1$ in the $ij$ slot and $0$s elsewhere.